# Pythonic way for checking equality in AND condition

Tags: python

I have a piece of code which looks like below:

```
a = None
b = None
c = None
d = None

if a==None and b==None and c==None and d==None:
    print("All are None")
else:
    print("Someone is not None")
```

What would be the pythonic way or shorter way to achieve this as I have more number of variables to check like this?

Comment: well these variables comes from frontend,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list, and check all items in the list using list comprehension:

```
l_list = [None, None, None, None, None]
if all(item is None for item in l_list):
    print("All items are None")
```

Comment: This approach is working for me, but there are some more answers which is giving the same results as I want. If possible could you explain me which could be an efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

You can chain the comparisons:

```
if a is b is c is d is None:
    print("All are None")
else:
    print("Someone is not None")
```

Answer (score -1):

`if not all((a, b, c, d)):`

or

`if not any((a, b, c, d)):` if you want to check if any of the item is not `None`

Does this help?

Comment: Nope, If I change None to some value in any of variable, it still goes in if condtion, it should go in else printing "Some one is not none".  If all the variables are not None, then it goes to else condition

Comment: Since the OP is asking if items are `None` you need to test against it specifically. Consider the possibility that these variables might be `0`, `False`, `[]`, etc.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, I agree.